# JQuery Datatables in ASP.NET (...).DataTables is not a function

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to use JQuery datatables in my cshtml file, but I get the error: $(...).DataTable is not a function.

This is what I do:

```
 @model IEnumerable<VannNettAdmin.Models.Classification.blabla>

 @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
 }

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#test').DataTable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Index</h2>
  <table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-striped cf">
     <thead class="cf">
       <tr>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.blabla)
          </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blabla)
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

My layout file:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Kvm3n2VXx7/

Comment: Will you post your full view code? I can't determine if you're using a layout or scripts render section

Comment: Looks like you're using MVC - MVC includes jquery in the bundles at the bottom of the page - but you also have it included in the `<head>` - ie you're loading it twice.  The 2nd load effectively unloads datatables.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file you already have a head tag and body tag, it is not advised to have those elements duplicated. You also have to utilize @rendersection scripts to add the script files from the view to the layout. Follow the steps below;

1. Add this at the end of the head tag in your layout file

```
@RenderSection("styles", required: false)
```

2. Remove the body, head tag from your view file.
3. Remove JQUERY from your view file, don't duplicate, they might have conflicting functionalities.
4. Use `@section scripts { ... }` and `@section styles { ... }` to place the view files in a specific position in the layout file.

This should be your the resulting view file.

```
@model IEnumerable<VannNettAdmin.Models.Classification.blabla>

@{ Layout = "_LayoutFileName"; }
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-striped cf">
   <thead class="cf">
      <tr>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.blabla)
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model) {
         <tr>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blabla)
            </td>
         </tr>
      }
   </tbody>
</table>

@section styles{
   <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
}

@section scripts{
   <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function () {
         $('#test').DataTable();
      });
   </script>
}
```

---

mData of undefined error is caused by not equal number of `th` and `td`.

So if you add a `td`, you should also add a corresponding `th`; If you have 2 `td`, it is required that you have 2 `th` as well.

```
<table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-striped cf">
     <thead class="cf">
       <tr>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.blabla)
          </th>
          <th>
            Options
          </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blabla)
         </td>
         <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { climatezoneId = item.ClimateZoneId})
         </td>
       </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209888/discussion-on-answer-by-jerdine-sabio-jquery-datatables-in-asp-net-datatab).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#test').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Remove your script from head tag and add it before ending body tag.
Moreover, make sure that jQuery is not loaded twice or more on the page.